# remove blue background color in Python OpenCV

Tags: opencv, python

[image]

the task is to remove the blue background in the picture, how can I implement that?

Comment: This shows very little effort. Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far? What do you expect? What error do you get? For help, take a look at [ask] or consider taking the [tour].
Some ideas: Mask the object using `findcontours` or remove every pixel within a certain color range. This shouldn't be a difficult task.

Comment: Threshold on blue using cv2.inRange() and negate. Use some morphology to clean it up. That gives you a mask. Put the mask into the alpha channel of your input image to make the blue background transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You should listen @fmw42, as he suggested, you could perform color segmentation to get the binary mask. Then using binary mask, you can remove the background.

- 1. **Performing color-segmentation:** As @fmw42 suggested, we convert the loaded image to the HSV format define lower/upper ranges and perform color segmentation using [`cv2.inRange`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html) to obtain a binary mask
- 2. **Extracting rod:** After obtaining binary mask we will use it to remove the background and separate rod from the rest of the image using [`cv2.bitwise_and`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html). Arithmetic operation and is highly useful for defining roi in hsv colored images.

---

- Result will be:

  - [image]

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("iSXsL.jpg")

# Convert to HSV color-space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Perform color-segmentation to get the binary mask
lwr = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upr = np.array([179, 255, 146])
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, lwr, upr)

# Extracting the rod using binary-mask
krn = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 3))
dlt = cv2.dilate(msk, krn, iterations=5)
res = 255 - cv2.bitwise_and(dlt, msk)

# Display
cv2.imshow("res", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```